# Create inherited object based on runtime value

Tags: c++, inheritance, runtime

Is there a way in C++ to create an instance of class based on runtime argument ? Here is code example :

```
class base
{
public:
    base(int a) : a_(a) {}
    virtual void print()
    {
        cout << "base";
    }
    int a_;
};

class A : public base
{
    A(int a = 5) : a_(a), base(a) {}
    void print() override
    {
        cout << "class A";
    }
    int a_;
};

class B : public base
{
    B(int a = 6) : a_(a), base(a) {}
    void print() override
    {
        cout << "class B";
    }
    int a_;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int a = std::cin.get();
    base childClass(a);
    childClass.print();
}
```

Now lets say that when I put 5 on `std::cin`, and call `print()` it will print "class A".

I know that `A(int a = 5)` just means that default value will be set on 5 if no parameter will be passed, its just for better clarification.

I dont want solution based on `if(a == 5) A a(5); a.print(); else if(a == 6) ...` or `switch(a) ...`

Comment: The solution you don't want is the only way this can be done in C++. There's very little that C++ will do for you automatically, you have to do all the work yourself. If not this kind of an explicit construction, but something along the same lines, like a helper map of constructors, or maybe script-generated code. There are many different approaches but they all boil down to the same thing: code that constructs an instance of each class, and some logic to decide which code to use, for a particular class instance. That's it.

Comment: what Sam said, but you can wrap the `if` or `switch` inside a factory function that returns a `base*` (or appropriate smart pointer), thats how it is commonly done

Comment: There are some ways to reduce the boiler plate, from template MP to macros to codegen, but for educational project like this one the boilerplate based on `switch` or `if` statements is probably the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question (Is there a way in C++ to create an instance of class based on runtime argument?) is yes. The response to what you don't want is "unfortunately you don't have a choice."

However, this is mitigated by doing it in a function that you only have to write once. The code below is a simple factory example. You pass parameters in to the factory, and it creates the object that was requested. C++ factories will pretty much always have to return a pointer to a heap allocated resource to function at run-time.

A smart pointer, `std::unique_ptr` was used to store the object so that we don't have to remember to manually `delete` it ourselves.

There are other methods, like resource pools, but no matter what at some point you'll need to `switch` or `if/else` to get the proper resource.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Base {
  virtual ~Base() = default;  // Required
  virtual void print() = 0;
};

struct A : public Base {
  void print() override { std::cout << "A\n"; }
};

struct B : public Base {
  void print() override { std::cout << "B\n"; }
};

struct C : public Base {
  void print() override { std::cout << "C\n"; }
};

Base* factory(char obj) {
  switch (obj) {
    case 'a':
      [[fallthrough]];
    case 'A':
      return new A;
    case 'b':
      [[fallthrough]];
    case 'B':
      return new B;
    case 'c':
      [[fallthrough]];
    case 'C':
      return new C;
    default:  // Could optionally throw to avoid the nullptr check in main()
      std::cerr << "Bad option given to factory\n";
      return nullptr;
  }
}

int main() {
  char want;
  std::cout << "Object: ";
  std::cin >> want;

  // Saves you having to manually `delete` the pointer
  std::unique_ptr<Base> obj(factory(want));

  if (obj) {
    obj->print();
  } else {
    std::cout << "Nothing\n";
  }
}
```

If new sub-types get added down the line, a new case is not a huge thing, although you now have to update your code in two places. This can be mitigated somewhat if you merged your factory with something like an Observer. But no matter what, at some point you'll have to `if/else` or `switch`.